# Javascript timer not working..

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, timer

Here is my code, please tell me where I've made a mistake so I can learn from it and hopefully get it working :).

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="startTimer()" />
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var  Timer = 120;
var checkTimer = false;
var t;

function  countDown(){
doucment.getElementById("txt").value = Timer;
Timer--;
t = setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
}

function startTimer(){
if(!checkTimer){
checkTimer = true;
countDown();
}

else{
console.log("Error!");
}

}
```

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Simplicity Yes, here it is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: doucment is not defined

Comment: `doucment` != `document`

Comment: Beat me to it, also. I just learned that you can give setTimeout a string to 'eval'. Thanks for that. Learn something new everyday

Comment: @CraigLafferty personally I hate string eval functions like that. `t = setTimeout(() => countDown(), 1000)` or if no params/extra lines of code: `t = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);`

Comment: I agree, it's the equivalent of eval and hard to maintain/read. I just appreciate that someone taught me yet another js quirk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your code in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4uj8z3u/2/)

Had me stumble across a few things,

1. The `startTimer()` in the `onclick` wasn't found.
2. `doucment` !== `document` as pointed out by [Sterling Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774078/sterling-archer)
3. The string eval could be changed to `t = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);` also pointed out by [Sterling Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774078/sterling-archer)

Now let's go to the solution.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<!-- Removed the onclick attribute and added an ID for the eventListener -->
<input type="button" value="Start Timer" id="start" />
```

**JS**

```
//Event listener for the button. Same as the onClick, this one, however, does work.
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", startTimer, false);

var Timer = 120;
var checkTimer = false;
var t;

function countDown() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = Timer;
  Timer--;
  t = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
}

function startTimer() {
  if (!checkTimer) {
    checkTimer = true;
    countDown();
  } else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }

}
```

What I've done is:

- I've added an event listener to counter the `startTimer()` "cannot be found" error
- I've changed `doucment` to `document`
- and I've changed your string eval to `t = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);`

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, glad to help out, considering you're rather new to SO, please consider reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @KhalidAlmalki

Comment: @KhalidAlmalki There was no issue with the way you were initially setting your `onclick`. The only issue was the way Simplicity set up his fiddle. As long as you place your script just before the closing body tag, your previous method is fine.

Answer (score -3):

You have a typo. You should have `document.getElementById("txt")` not `doucment.getElementById("txt")`. Try this:

```
var Timer = 120;
var checkTimer = false;
var t;

function countDown() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = Timer;
  Timer--;
  t = setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
}

function startTimer() {
  if (!checkTimer) {
    checkTimer = true;
    countDown();
  } else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }

}
```

---

**Update:**
If you would like for the timer to stop at zero, you will need to add an if statement to see if the timer is greater than 0 before decrementing the timer again. That would look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="startTimer()" />
```

**JS:**

```
var Timer = 120;
var checkTimer = false;
var t;

function countDown() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = Timer;
  if (Timer > 0){
    Timer--;
  }
  t = setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
}

function startTimer() {
  if (!checkTimer) {
    checkTimer = true;
    countDown();
  } else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/moks2oyb/

Further improvements could be made to this code, but this is meant to illustrate that your code will work once the errors are fixed.

Comment: Oh, that was a silly thing to do! Sorry about that, I just started to learn JS and I was trying out what I've learn't! Thank you!

Comment: You did not fix the error, nor did you explain what you fixed.

Comment: It counts down now.. but it goes into negative?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I fixed the typo which was the first issue I saw. I have update with a more thorough answer.

Comment: @KhalidAlmalki Check the update for the version that stops at zero